# Creating XLWorkbook from memory stream

Tags: c#, xml, ssrs-2012, closedxml

I want to create XLWorkbook object from memory stream. Bytes of xlsx file are written to the memory stream. But when I try to create XLWorkbook object I get exceptio: NullReference exception was caught. Can anyone help me with this?

```
//...
ssrsHelper.ExecuteReport( model, "EXCELOPENXML" );

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
memStream.Write( model.ReportBits, 0, model.ReportBits.Length );

//in this line I get the exception
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook( memStream, XLEventTracking.Disabled );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (under the assumption that `model.ReportBits` is a valid byte array that  is in a valid xlsx file format):

```
using(MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    memStream.Write(model.ReportBits, 0, model.ReportBits.Length);
    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(memStream, XLEventTracking.Disabled);
    /*  ... */
    wb.SaveAs(pathToSavedFile);
}
```